# The database calculated field not updated, for example total= qte*price when qte or price are updated

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, dbgrid

I designed a Firebird table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE LINES
(
    PK bigint NOT NULL,
    NDOC bigint,
    NART bigint,
    CLOT varchar(10),
    DATE_PER date,
    QTE numeric(18,2),
    Price numeric(7,2),
    PPA numeric(7,2),

    CONSTRAINT PK_LIGNES_0 PRIMARY KEY (PK)
);

ALTER TABLE LINES ADD MNT COMPUTED BY (qte*price);
```

The data is shown in a dbgrid; when I update qte or price the field MNT does not get updated.

Comment: Computed columns are read only virtual columns (some DBs allow you to persist them). After inserting a line or updating the associated columns, you need to re-query the database to retrieve the value of the computed column. The way that queries behave won't work as you want. You can create the same field in the Delphi DataSet as a calculated field.

Comment: Do you mean the field is not updated in the grid, or also not updated when you execute the query again? Because the changes will only be reflected in the grid if the row is requeried by the grid or by you, or the grid emulates the computation performed by the database.

Comment: Solved.  Calculated field  is the trick, but which is better :Re-SELECT or Calculate ?

Comment: Calculated field is (normally) locally in your program via code. COMPUTED fields are done via the database engine and need to be refreshed/reread to your program on update. COMPUTED by the engine would be preferred because if you 'forget' to update your calculated field in your program (or the field is updated outside your program) the MNT fields doesn't hold the correct value anymore. (and it occupies space of a numeric which a COMPUTED field doesn't.)

Comment: I do not know in AnyDAC brought smoething new, but for what i remember Delphi `TDataSet` and `TField` had two kinds of calculated fields: calculated on server and calculated on client (inside the application). I think the latter was called `fkUserCalc` (where "user" of data was meant to be the program), and the former - `fkCalculated`, and de-facto it just mean the field is read-only. So, if you want the column to be re-calculatedon the server, then you have to post the canged data into the database, adnd then re-read the DataSet back form server (via `close`/`open` or `refresh`)

Comment: This might be slow and "blinking". So you may chose another approach - do not read that column from the server at all, and create the 'virtual' `fkUserCalc` column in your dataset, then make the calculation in Delphi code using `TDataset.OnCalcFields` event. This however means you wrote the code twice, in SQL and in Delphi, and as always is with copy-paste, later, when someone might change the program, he might update one place and forget to update another.  You have to choose what you consider least evil.